# Compilation Error after integrating VS2017 and Sitecore 9.3

Tags: configuration, mvc, site-configuration, sitecore-install-assistant

I am newbie to 9.3,

1. Installed and browsed the Sitecore project.
2. Tried to integrate with Visual project by adding reference files `sitecore.kernel.dll, sitecore.client.dll, system.web.mvc` and deleted the `Global.asax` and web config files and replaced those files from Inetpub.

While Building the project zero errors, but while browsing the Sitecore site I'm getting a compilation error.

> The type or namespace name 'DummySitecoreProject' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".(VS
> project name DummySitecoreProject)

[image]

Comment: Did you deploy your project to the website folder?

Comment: Did you mean copying the DLL of VS project to website folder? if that is the question yes i have added the DLL of VS project to bin of website folder.